# Bath tub spout still drips a little after replacing, is this normal?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, bathtub, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

I didn't notice the leaking from the spout until some guests told me. It was dripping big drops. The spout is the type installing using hexa bolt. I bought the replacement at [HomeDepot](http://www.homedepot.com/p/PartsmasterPro-Adjustable-Tub-Spout-with-Front-Diverter-in-Chrome-Finish-58248/203052401) and followed the instruction [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcBdjH4Fdik)

Now I notice there are still tiny drops of dripping (exact spot in the pic). Not a lot of water I think. The faucet is still fine, no dripping there.

Is this normal for this type of spout? Should I be concerned about bigger leak elsewhere?

Thanks,

[image]
[image]

Comment: The spout is just the outlet through which the drips are flowing. It has no influence on whether there are drips or not. If you shut off the faucet and there's still water coming out (drips) then it's the faucet that's at fault, not the spout.

Comment: If dropping all the time I think you replaced the wrong part.  The guts or cartridge inside the knob (marked existing in your photo) is whats leaking and needs replacement.

Comment: Thanks all, from Moen website, it looks like I can buy a replacing cartridge http://www.moen.com/product-support/chateau/chrome-standard-tub-shower/_/R-IMGLIB%3A2719?catalogSku=IMGLIB:2719&support=replacement-parts

Comment: The water may also be that standing in the pipe from the diverter (in the faucet) to the shower head. Normally, there is an **intentional** small leak at the faucet end to allow the pipe to drain in a minute or two, at which time the diverter handle drops (usually with a little "clunk"). There's no need to do anything unless the faucet keeps dripping for more than a few minutes after the handle drops back..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I bought the replacing cartridge in my comment, and followed the instruction  [here](https://youtu.be/b7Z2KsD706M?list=PL3U7jNbIt-LPG7U-UWW1VKg_RbaOjoaYf). Super easy and no need trick or anything. The whole old cartridge came out easily, unlike other videos.